# Can I ceiling mount a 15 lbs projector on drywall + 0.5 inch plywood?

Tags: ceiling, screws, mounting, drywall-anchor, projector

I am about to mount a 15 lbs projector ( x3000i ) on my ceiling.  None of my ceiling joist is at dead center so I drilled a 0.5 inch plywood ( 30inch x  20inch ) between two joists.

Now can I mount this projector on this 0.5 inch plywood + drywall?  Projector mount came with long washer head screw and the manual says to drill 2.5 inch deep with 5/32 drill bit. Can I just drill this screw even though I don't even have 2.5inch thick wood in between?  Or do I need to use some kind of anchor?

Washer head screw:
[image: Washer head screw]

Ceiling with plywood:
[image: Ceiling with plywood]

Comment: @Ruskes that's only if the screw happens to hit a joist.  Really, the screw only needs to be about 3/4" longer than the thickness of the projector mount (1/2" ply, 1/4" to account for the screw taper).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That screw will work but is unnecessarily long and fat.  You'll have to predrill and hope you don't encounter anything inside the ceiling.  You seem to have a sprinkler head there, so you especially hope not to hit its supply.  I also wonder whether the thread on your screw is too coarse for a 1/2 inch board making it potentially weaker than a more appropriate one... not sure.

Assuming the projector mount uses four screws and a fairly thin piece of sheet metal (thin enough you don't need to account for it in the screw length) I would use a #8 x 1 inch (or whatever reasonable length you have a box of) without even drilling.  It'll take you 3 minutes. The screws will fully engage the plywood and won't exit the drywall.

Comment: Perfect answer. I would also suggest: Before screwing the projector in place, give the plywood a quick coat of white paint. Let it dry, then screw in the projector. With white paint, even if it is not a perfect match to the rest of the ceiling, the plywood will not look out of place as it does now.

Comment: yes, unless you have some spare paint that matches the ceiling use white paint or paint that matches the projector or projector bracket.   or get a "test pot" that fully matches, it should have just enough.

Comment: OP could even get some molding and frame out the edges of the plywood piece, for a more "finished" look.

Comment: I will white paint it. My projector x3000i is also white.